# Internal server error on second step of split sign-up journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

If I attempt to both separate email verification and user registration ([as per this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)) and use custom email verification ([as per this one](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol)) in the same policy, I get a non-descript "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred" 500 error after successful email validation but before the 2nd self-assertion screen is displayed.  App Insights logging states that the policy transitioned to a Microsoft.Cpim.Common.PolicyException state, possibly after an IsSelfAssertedEmpty predicate returned true.  But nothing in the logging suggests what's empty and as best I can tell nothing is.  Any ideas either how to fix this issue or how to diagnose the cause?

Comment: No errors or exceptions in the log? I've found the best way is to export all columns and then open in Notepad++ and then search/page down through the file. Failing that, comment out the flow and add it back piece by piece.

Comment: And in insights, limit the log to the last 30 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) for splitting email verification and sign-up includes a 'PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"' attribute on the email output claim on the verification technical profile.  Somehow, the out of the box email verification control provides this partner claim, whereas the custom control defined in their custom email [example](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol) does not.  I can't say I understand how this works since display controls can't have output claims, but removing the partner claim reference solves the 500 error.